# System requirements for Wakanda Server

Tags: javascript, system, requirements, wakanda

When deploying a Wakanda (javascript) app with Wakanda server, what are the minimum  system requirements? And what system requirements can be recommended to customers?
Are there any limitations to specific Windows or macOS versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Wakanda Server was release the system requirements available were:

```
- Mac OS X 10.6 or above
- Windows Vista or above/Windows Server 2008 or above
- Linux Ubuntu distribution 10.4 or 10.10 or above
- 1GB RAM (2GB recommended)
```

[source](http://www.4d.com/au/comment/reply/24396)

However if you try running an instance of Wakanda Server on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine you can easily verify that `wakanda-server` process in idle state consume only up to 32mb of memory.

As initially suggested 1GB/2GB RAM can be considered a safe enough amount of memory to run a medium size application. A small application should be able to run in a 512MB environment without issues.

You should keep in mind that these are indicative amounts. The requirements of two applications can be drastically different even with the same number of users.